# Confusion about "as...as + clause"

Tags: clauses, as

I want to ask a question about "as....as" uses. I think it is very confusing. In *Meditations, 3.3* Marcus Aurelius says:

> [...] you will no longer be exposed to pain and pleasure, or be the servant of an earthen vessel **as inferior in value as that serving it is superior**, the servant being mind and guardian-spirit and the master mud and gore.

I actually can't understand the uses of as in this paragraph and so the meaning.

By the way full text is that:

> You climbed aboard, you set sail, and now you have come to port. So step ashore! If to another life, there will be no want of gods even in that other world; but if to insensibility, you will no longer be exposed to pain and pleasure, or be the servant of an earthen vessel as inferior in value as that serving it is superior, the servant being mind and guardian-spirit and the master mud and gore. — Meditations, 3.3

Comment: Is that the Gregory Hays translation? Said to be the best one.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is by Robin Hard. I checked Gregory Hays's translation. I think you are right.  Hays's translation is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says,

You and the master are like two clay bowls. But he is as worthless as you - his servant - are valuable, because you are mind and guardian-spirit and he is mud and gore.

In other words, the master-bowl is worth little: the servant-bowl is worth a lot.

There may be a suggestion of the servant filling the master's bowl. I think these bowls are drinking-vessels.

Some similar comparisons might help:

> The snake was as long as the boy was tall. (e.g. Snake 1 meter long: boy 1 metre tall.)
>
> He is as stingy as his father is generous.
>
> She's as wise as he is ignorant.

Comment: Thank you for responding Old Brixtonian. I understood meaning of the paragraph due to your explanation. But I have an another question. The structure of the sentence after second "as" looks interesting. I mean in this sentence "as that serving it is superior", the subject is "that serving" so why there is "it". I mean if it had been said "as that serving is superior" it would be enough for the meaning. Shortly why there's "it" after "that" in the sentence. Because there's already "that". So what it is the reason for putting "it" after "that". Or maybe I analyze the structure wrongly.

Comment: "as that serving it" means "as the person serving him". Having called the master, metaphorically, *an earthen vessel*, the pronoun 'it' is needed rather than 'him'. Got it? It is rather convoluted.

Comment: Wow, amazing! Now, I understood the text exactly. Thank you so much Old Brixtonian.